# Error:-[libx264 @ 000001fa2ffdd080] height not divisible by 2 (244x207)

Tags: ffmpeg

I was looking to put an audio visualiser filter on my podcast file(mp3)and got the necessary code from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5dCKuN9Ius).But on running the code,the terminal gave an error"height not divisible by 2".I tried my best to apply the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2) but it didn't work.Any suggestions would be helpful.

Code:

> ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=White:mode=p2p,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:200[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output12.mp4

Error Log:

> ffmpeg version N-90762-g223f3dff8c Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
>     libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
>     libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
>     libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
>     libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
>     libavfilter     7. 18.100 /  7. 18.100
>     libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
>     libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
>     libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
>   [mp3 @ 000001fa2ffdabc0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>   Input #0, mp3, from 'fast.mp3':
>     Duration: 00:00:13.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
>   Input #1, png_pipe, from 'scott.png':
>     Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 244x207 [SAR 1:1 DAR 244:207], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> showwaves
>     Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:main
>     overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [libx264 @ 000001fa2ffdd080] height not divisible by 2 (244x207)
>   Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
>   Conversion failed!

Comment: Set size in showwaves to 1280x176.

Comment: @Gyan tried 1280x174,1280x175,1280x176  - not working

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=2*trunc(iw*sar/2):2*trunc(ih/2)[bg];[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=White:mode=p2p,format=yuv420p[v];[bg][v]overlay=0:200[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output12.mp4`

Since the image is the base layer, its dimensions should be made even.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like FFmpeg scaling doesn't work well on **"odd dimensions"**. I manually changed the image dimensions to 244×207 to 244×208 [**even**] (using MS Paint resize option) now everything works fine!

[image]

[image]

Comment: *It looks like ffmpeg scaling doesn't work well on "odd dimensions"* --> what does this mean?

Comment: odd is the opposite of even, They are numbers that are not multiples of 2.

Comment: you didn't use scale in your original command. It's not only ffmpeg's issue - the x264 codec requires the output to be divisible by 2 (both height and width). Therefor if you feed an image with not divisible by 2 dimensions, you must scale it: filter_complex "1 scale=244:208 [img]" or you can pad it with color pixel "1 pad=h=208 [img]" see more in docs.